# Как определить поддерживает ли шрифт lowercase/uppercase режим в iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Я использую в приложение кастомные шрифты. Количество шрифтов не ограниченно. Некоторые шрифты не имеют поддержки lowercase, но мне нужно включать/выключать lowercase/uppercase кнопку в UI. Как можно определить, поддерживает ли шрифт lowercase и uppercase или только один из режимов?

Comment: Можете привести пример шрифта, не поддерживающего lowercase? Хочу сделать пару экспериментов.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk да, конечно Horizon . Я смотрел в Google Fonts нету нашего варианта, я спросил у менеджера могу ли я выложить данный файл в открытый доступ, если ответ будет положительный я вам дам ссылку на файл

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk посмотрите пожалуйста Impact Label и Bebas Neue шрифты

Comment: Попробовал. К сожалению я не нашел такого способа. Встроенные функции UIFont capHeight и lineHeight выдают неверное значение.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk спасибо за ответ